# Wordpress site slowed down due to css file from localhost

Tags: wordpress

I got my wordpress site load up and running LIVE but it's very slow. Now after hours of search I found out in the source code that I got a stylesheet linked as

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wpfb-css'  href='http://localhost:8888/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/wp-filebase/wp-filebase.css?ver=0.3.0.05' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

which means a css file has come from my local development server that I have offline...

Where is this file usually located at and what should I do to officialy remove it so my wordpress site can run smoothly again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to update he "wpfb_css" field on the database:

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "http://newdomain.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-filebase/wp-filebase.css" WHERE option_name = 'wpfb_css';

Answer (score -1):

Change in your template to link to it like this;

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wpfb-css'  href='/wp-content/plugins/wp-filebase/wp-filebase.css?ver=0.3.0.05' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

This uses an absolute path, without the domain, assuming your website loads at the base url, not in a sub directory, else prepend the subdirectory.

This should then work regardless of being on your dev environment or your production server.

[Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

The reason it's slowed down is because ordinarily it'd be a 404 error, but as every client has a localhost, the request isn't instantly dismissed by a server with a 404, so it's timing out when eventually port 8888 doesn't get a connection.

Comment: I deleted the whole plugin but my website is still loading very slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Poor performance, either application or server tuning is another question. Has the 404 situation been resolved now the plugin is removed? Look in the network inspector and make sure all resources have 200 (success) or 304 (not modified) status.

Is the website online? Do you have a link?

Comment: The URL for filebase is generated by the plugin. Modifying the template its not enough.